# Naming the intersection points of two paths in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the ellipse below which has two marked points, red and green, computed using the intersections library of TikZ.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary {intersections} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (CTRL)     at (0,0) ;
  \node[draw, black, thick, ellipse,
  minimum height=3cm, minimum width=2cm,
  name=ctrl,
  name path=ctrl] at (CTRL) {Control};

  \gettikzxy{(ctrl.south)}{\csx}{\csy}
  \gettikzxy{(ctrl.north)}{\cnx}{\cny}
  
  \coordinate (C1) at ($(\csx,\csy) + 1/7*(0,\cny-\csy)$) ;
  \path[name path=lev1] ($(C1)+(-2,0)$) -- ($(C1) + (2,0)$);

  \coordinate (C2) at ($(\csx,\csy) + 2/7*(0,\cny-\csy)$) ;
  \path[name path=lev2] ($(C2)+(-2,0)$) -- ($(C2) + (2,0)$);

% how do I name this intersection as I1?
  \fill [red,name intersections={of=ctrl and lev1}] (intersection-2) circle (2pt) node {}; 
 % how do I name this intersection as I2?
  \fill [green,name intersections={of=ctrl and lev2}] (intersection-2) circle (2pt) node {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**I want to the name the red point as `I1` and green point as `I2`, so that I can use them in drawing paths later on in my code. How do I do that?**

I tried looking at the documentation of intersection given [here](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#tikz/name:intersections); using the `by` option *almost* seems to answer the question, but when I tried using as follows in the option to `\fill`

```
  \fill [red,name intersections={of=ctrl and lev1},by={a,b}] (b) circle (2pt) node {};
```

I got the error

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/by', to which you passed 
'a,I1', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.34 ...ntersections={of=ctrl and lev1},by={a,I1}]
                                                   (I1) circle (2pt) node {}...
```

Comment: You have to write `by={...}` inside the `name intersections={...}` braces.

Comment: It's not what you asked for but I think you could place your points directly on your curve at a fraction of the arc going from south to north, if that's your intention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

- Naming of path intersections are described in the `tikz` package documentation, *section 13.3.2 Intersections of Arbitrary Paths*, page 145.
- your MWE compile without any errors or warnings, but if you like to change intersection names, you need to declare in command for example like this

```
\fill [name intersections={of=..., by=I1}, red]  (I1) circle[radius=2pt];
```

- your MWE can be make a bit shorter (and simpler) by use of different way of coordinates `C1` and `C2` calculation and defining of intersections:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                intersections,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
E/.style = {ellipse, draw, thick, 
            minimum height=3cm, minimum width=2cm}
                        ]
% elipse
\node[E, name path=C] (ctrl)  {Control};

\coordinate (C1) at ($ (ctrl.south)!1/7!(ctrl.north) $);
\coordinate (C2) at ($ (ctrl.south)!2/7!(ctrl.north) $);

\path[name path=A] (C1) -- ++ (1,0);  % changed
\path[name path=B] (C2) -- ++ (1,0);  % changed
% intersections
\fill [name intersections={of=C and A, by=I1}, red]  (I1) circle[radius=2pt)];
\fill [name intersections={of=C and B, by=I2}, teal] (I2) circle[radius=2pt)];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]